# EF6, MVC 5 and Oracle Database

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, entity-framework

First of all, I want to apologize for my mistake in English, I’m native French.

I need help, because i’m block now from few day, on my web application i’m trying to start. I explain, I’m developing a new web app. This app is make like the following picture :

I have 1 solution, contain 2 project, first, the _DLL project is the library class project, and it’s to connet to the Oracle Database
This database is correctly connected, and I can generate the Entity to make a DataBase first
The _WebSite contain a MVC design patern, with actually, nothing special.

**History :**

I created this solution on VS 2015, and i’m trying to using entity framework 6.1.3. This is installed on the both project
The _DLL Project, contraint the references to the ODT Oracle, the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.
The version of ODT installed, is the 12.1.0.2.4 (the last one, release the 5 October, and rules with VisualStudio 2015) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html
Following the step, I created a EDMX, based on a my tab name : "Pilier", juste to try the connexion and if everything is working fine

After thats, I add the references to the : _DLL project on my _WebSite project. Next step, générate the MVC with view, using EF 6.

**Actually**

**App.config (_DLL Project)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>

  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.121.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=****;PASSWORD=*******;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=SAGEX&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>


  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="4.121.1.0">
      <settings>
        <setting name="AGPD" value="C:\app\client\uadmin\product\12.1.0\client_2\Network\Admin" />
      </settings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>

</configuration>
```

**Web.config (_WebSite Project)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Pour plus d’informations sur la configuration de votre application ASP.NET, rendez-vous sur 
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>


  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EntityModel.csdl|res://*/EntityModel.ssdl|res://*/EntityModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=*****;PASSWORD=*******;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=SAGEX&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**Problem**

Here, everything become strange and unsolvable… when I lunch my asp.net website, this error append.:

This is the error :

*Une exception de type 'System.InvalidOperationException' s'est produite dans mscorlib.dll mais n'a pas été gérée dans le code utilisateur

Informations supplémentaires : The Entity Framework provider type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.*

I found somes people with problem, but no one of the solution purpose on different website, allow me to continue… somebody can help me ?.
Thanks.

Comment: No one? it's not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration is loaded from your `Web.config` file. The `App.config` file on the dll project  file is ignored, in your particular case the solution could be as simple as adding:

```xml
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

to your `Web.config` file.  Your connection string and other relevant config entries need to be present in your `Web.config` file also and not in the `App.config` file of your dll project.